# How to install the latest version of Git on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, git

I have version 2.5 of Git on Ubuntu:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.5.0
```

but Git is at version 2.7.1 now.  The Git website says to do

```
apt-get install git
```

to install it.  But I tried both `sudo apt-get install git` and `sudo apt-get upgrade git` and it is still version 2.5.  How do I upgrade it to the latest version?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/568596/158442